# Block procedure PL/SQL with Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, procedure

I have a procedure and I would like that only one user could execute this procedure at same time.

Answer (score 12):

This is just off the top of my head:  Consider using a named lock via dbms_lock.
http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_lock.htm#CHDICHDC

Right after the begin statement get the lock, do the work, then release it on
exit (Keep errors/exceptions in mind!).

KT

Comment: I've used this method before, it works nicely - http://jeffkemponoracle.blogspot.com/2005/10/user-named-locks-with-dbmslock.html

Answer (score -1):

A simple solution can be to use lock at the table level, by using FOR UPDATE.