# Is there a best way to avoid execution of process more than once in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, plsql

Let's say that I have a `procedure` called `myproc`. This is a complex process and i cannot allow two instances executing at the same time the proc.

Actually I do this using the `dbms_application_info.set_module`:

```
procedure start_process is
begin
  dbms_application_info.set_module('myproc', 'running');
end;
```

and verify before run the process:

```
select 'S'
  from v$session v
 where v.module = 'myproc'
   and v.action = 'running';
```

In the database level, is there a better way to check this?

Comment: +1 good question, but `v$session` is not unique on module, action so it would be easy to be wrong.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053484/block-procedure-pl-sql-with-oracle

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [dbms_lock.allocate_unique](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_lock.htm#i1002533) along with [dbms_lock.request](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_lock.htm#i1002556). The **usage notes** says:

> The first session to call ALLOCATE_UNIQUE with a new lock name causes 
>   a unique lock ID to be generated and stored in the dbms_lock_allocated  table. 
>   Subsequent calls (usually by other sessions) return the lock ID previously generated.

I think this could be what you're after.

Comment: +1, this is a much better idea than mine... I'm too used to collecting loads of metadata at the same time as doing other things.

Comment: Really interesting feature. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can create a table `processes`. You also ensure that each process has some sort of unique identifier - for instance a hash of the `owner, object_name` from [`dba_objects`](http://ss64.com/orad/DBA_OBJECTS.html) so you could create this dynamically in your package.

You then create a function to [lock each row individually](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25789/consist.htm#CNCPT1341) as a process is run.

As @Sergio pointed out in the comments this would not work if for some reason you needed to commit in the middle of the process - unless, of course, you re-selected after each commit.

```
function locking ( Pid ) return number is

   l_locked number := 0;

begin

   select 1
     into l_locked
     from processes
    where id = Pid
         -- exit immediately if the proc is running
      for update nowait
          ;

   return l_locked;

   exception when others then
      return 0;

end;
```

This has the benefit of locking that row in `processes` for you until the session that's currently running your procedure has finished.

You then wrap this in your procedure:

```
-- if we failed to lock locking will have thrown an error
-- i.e. we have 0 here.
if locking( 123 ) = 0 then
   exit;
end if;
```

As long as each procedure has a unique id - the important bit - your procedure will exit cleanly.

---

It might not apply in your situation but, my normal way of doing this is to use [`mod`](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/mod.php). Though it doesn't stop 2 of the same process running it does ensure that when you have more than 1 you only run them on different data. Something like as follows:

```
procedure my_procedure ( PNumerator number, PDenominator number ) is

    cursor c_my_cursor ( CNumerator number, CDenominator number ) is
     select columns
       from my_table
      where mod( ascii(substr(id, -1)), CDenominator ) = CNumerator
            ;

begin
   open c_my_cursor( PNumerator, PDenominator );
   ...    
end;
```

Comment: This broke if you need for some reason commit in the middle of the process, right?