# One Oracle scheduled job runs parallel with another instance. How to prevent this?

Tags: oracle, plsql, scheduled-tasks, dbms-scheduler

I have a stored PL/SQL procedure which starts every 10 minutes (scheduled job). Sometimes my procedure executes for more than 10 minutes. In this case, Oracle scheduler runs another instance of my procedure in parallel with the first one. How can I prevent Oracle from starting a new procedure until the first one is finished?

Comment: Related questions: [Create a “barrier” (prevent parallel execution) in Oracle PL/SQL?](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/30774/create-a-barrier-prevent-parallel-execution-in-oracle-pl-sql) [Is there a best way to avoid execution of process more than once in Oracle?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9825012/is-there-a-best-way-to-avoid-execution-of-process-more-than-once-in-oracle)

Comment: pls post your scheduler code

Comment: default behavior is to not have instances of the same job running in parallel. So: how do you create that job exactly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't see the behavior you report, but again you can post your scheduler code since many options are available.

Setting up a basic test shows that the scheduler will actually skip a scheduled run of a job if the same job is already running.  In other words, it will wait until the first instance is complete before launching another (non-parallel).

This example fires an autonomous block that simply sleeps for 90 seconds, but it is scheduled to run every minute:

```
BEGIN
  dbms_scheduler.create_schedule('SCH_MINUTELY', systimestamp, 
    repeat_interval=>'FREQ=MINUTELY; INTERVAL=1');

  --dbms_scheduler.drop_job('JOB_TEST1', false);
  --dbms_scheduler.drop_chain('CHAIN_TEST1', false);
  --dbms_scheduler.drop_program('PROG_MAIN1', false);

  dbms_scheduler.create_program(program_name=>'PROG_MAIN1',program_type=>'PLSQL_BLOCK', 
    program_action=>'BEGIN
      dbms_lock.sleep(90);
    END;', 
    number_of_arguments=>0,enabled=>TRUE,comments=>'Runs for 90 seconds');

  -- create chain
  dbms_scheduler.create_chain(chain_name=>'CHAIN_TEST1',comments=>'A chain to test scheduler behavior');
  -- define chain steps
  dbms_scheduler.define_chain_step(chain_name=>'CHAIN_TEST1',step_name=>'STEP_RUN_MAIN',program_name=>'PROG_MAIN1');
  -- define chain rules
  dbms_scheduler.define_chain_rule(chain_name=>'CHAIN_TEST1',condition=>'TRUE',action=>'START "STEP_RUN_MAIN"',rule_name=>'CHAIN_TEST_R01',comments=>'Run main pgm');
  dbms_scheduler.define_chain_rule(chain_name=>'CHAIN_TEST1',condition=>'STEP_RUN_MAIN succeeded',action=>'END',rule_name=>'CHAIN_TEST_R02',comments=>'End of chain');
 -- enable chain
  dbms_scheduler.ENABLE ('CHAIN_TEST1');
  -- create job
  dbms_scheduler.create_job(job_name=>'JOB_TEST1',job_type=>'CHAIN',job_action=>'CHAIN_TEST1',schedule_name=>'SCH_MINUTELY',enabled=>TRUE,auto_drop=>FALSE,comments=>'Job to test scheduler');
END;
```

Looking at the scheduler logs (dba_scheduler_job_run_details):

```
LOG_DATE                               JOB_NAME                                                          JOB_SUBNAME                                                       STATUS                         ACTUAL_START_DATE                      RUN_DURATION
-------------------------------------- ----------------------------------------------------------------- ----------------------------------------------------------------- ------------------------------ -------------------------------------- ------------
23-SEP-13 10.49.34.332727000 AM -04:00 JOB_TEST1                                                                                                                           SUCCEEDED                      23-SEP-13 10.48.04.206153000 AM -04:00 0 0:1:30.0   
23-SEP-13 10.49.34.313332000 AM -04:00 JOB_TEST1                                                         STEP_RUN_MAIN                                                     SUCCEEDED                      23-SEP-13 10.48.04.302311000 AM -04:00 0 0:1:30.0   
23-SEP-13 10.47.34.231511000 AM -04:00 JOB_TEST1                                                                                                                           SUCCEEDED                      23-SEP-13 10.46.04.105827000 AM -04:00 0 0:1:30.0   
23-SEP-13 10.47.34.212905000 AM -04:00 JOB_TEST1                                                         STEP_RUN_MAIN                                                     SUCCEEDED                      23-SEP-13 10.46.04.200956000 AM -04:00 0 0:1:30.0   
23-SEP-13 10.45.34.144779000 AM -04:00 JOB_TEST1                                                                                                                           SUCCEEDED                      23-SEP-13 10.44.04.011605000 AM -04:00 0 0:1:30.0   
23-SEP-13 10.45.34.124745000 AM -04:00 JOB_TEST1                                                         STEP_RUN_MAIN                                                     SUCCEEDED                      23-SEP-13 10.44.04.113662000 AM -04:00 0 0:1:30.0   
23-SEP-13 10.43.35.048820000 AM -04:00 JOB_TEST1                                                                                                                           SUCCEEDED                      23-SEP-13 10.42.04.906209000 AM -04:00 0 0:1:30.0   
23-SEP-13 10.43.35.024348000 AM -04:00 JOB_TEST1                                                         STEP_RUN_MAIN                                                     SUCCEEDED                      23-SEP-13 10.42.05.012929000 AM -04:00 0 0:1:30.0   
23-SEP-13 10.41.34.950533000 AM -04:00 JOB_TEST1                                                                                                                           SUCCEEDED                      23-SEP-13 10.40.04.803192000 AM -04:00 0 0:1:30.0   
23-SEP-13 10.41.34.918242000 AM -04:00 JOB_TEST1                                                         STEP_RUN_MAIN                                                     SUCCEEDED                      23-SEP-13 10.40.04.900061000 AM -04:00 0 0:1:30.0   

 10 rows selected
```

We can see that while the Scheduler fires this job every minute, the job itself runs for 1.5 minutes, so:

```
time0: scheduler runs job  
time1: scheduler sees job is still running, does nothing 
time2: scheduler sees this job isnt running, runs job 
time3: scheduler sees job is still running, does nothing    
time4: scheduler sees this job isnt running, runs job
```

etc, etc

Comment: you were right - the second procedure will not start untill the first one finished. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

By using semaphore.. You could create a temporary table and insert a flag when your first procedure starts. And you should check that table if the first procedure started before you start second procedure. It is a simple semaphore logic.

Comment: someone once suggested I do this as well but it seems dangerous -- maintaining global state as a flag in a table. If it for any reason ever is not able to update the status at the end of the job, your job will never start back up again. It seems like a bit of an anti-pattern